# Issue Loading 300k records from Oracle database to ms sql db using ms sql linked server

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle

you help will be appreciated in advance. I need to load 300k records from one table in oracle database resided in deperate server to other table in ms sql db resided in other server using ms sql linked server. I need to load these 300k every day to keep my ms sql table up to dated. the problem is every time im running linked server query to load all 300k records, depending on free memory of server I load all 300k or other number of records less than 300k. 
My question is how i can make sure I load all those records everytime I run linked server query?

best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try SSIS and this is a very handy tool to do ETL.